# how to dynamically insert multiple rows into google cloud spanner

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, bulkinsert, google-cloud-spanner

In the below code snippet, Inserting multiple rows with static values. How do I insert multiple rows dynamically into the spanner database in one transaction?

```
 function writeUsingDml(instanceId, databaseId, projectId) {

  const {Spanner} = require('@google-cloud/spanner');

  const spanner = new Spanner({
      projectId: projectId,
  });

   const instance = spanner.instance(instanceId);
   const database = instance.database(databaseId);

  database.runTransaction(async (err, transaction) => {
     if (err) {
        console.error(err);
       return;
    }
try {
  const rowCount = await transaction.runUpdate({
    sql: `INSERT Singers (SingerId, FirstName, LastName) VALUES
    (12, 'Melissa', 'Garcia'),
    (13, 'Russell', 'Morales'),
    (14, 'Jacqueline', 'Long'),
    (15, 'Dylan', 'Shaw')`,
  });
  console.log(`${rowCount} records inserted.`);
  await transaction.commit();
} catch (err) {
  console.error('ERROR:', err);
} finally {
   database.close();
 }
});
}
```

For now, I am inserting a single row dynamically as follows and I want to extend this to multiple rows

```
 var sqlString = "Insert " + tName
 var cNames = "( "
 var cValues = "( "
 for(var col in cols) {
   cNames = cNames +  col +  ", " ;
   const cValue = cols[col];
   if (typeof cValue == 'string' || cValue instanceof String){
     cValues = cValues + "'" + cValue + "', "
   }else{
     cValues = cValues + cValue + ", ";
   }
  }
   return sqlString + cNames + ") values " + cValues + ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert many rows, it may be easier to use BatchTransaction.insert
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/spanner/2.1.x/BatchTransaction#insert

```
database.runTransaction(async (err, transaction) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    try {
        var itemsToInsert = [
            { SingerId: 12, FirstName: 'Mellissa', LastName: 'Garcia' },
            { SingerId: 13, FirstName: 'Russell', LastName: 'Morales' },
            { SingerId: 14, FirstName: 'Jacqueline', LastName: 'Long' },
            { SingerId: 15, FirstName: 'Dylan', LastName: 'Shaw' },
        ]

        transaction.insert('Singers', itemsToInsert);;
        await transaction.commit();
        console.log(`${itemsToInsert.length} records inserted.`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
    } finally {
        database.close();
    }
});
```

If you want to use DML though, you can make the SQL statement programatically. The following will build the insert statement. I didn't run your version, but I think it may have syntax errors related to trailing commas.

```
function buildSqlInsert(tableName, columnNames, rows) {
    var sqlString = "INSERT " + tableName + " (" + columnNames.join(', ') + ") VALUES \n";

    // add each row being careful to match the column order with columnNames
    rows.forEach(row => {
        sqlString += "(";
        columnNames.forEach(columnName => {
        var columnValue = row[columnName]
        // strings should be quoted
        if (typeof columnValue == 'string' || columnValue instanceof String) {
            columnValue = "'" + columnValue + "'";
        }
        sqlString += columnValue + ", ";
        });
        // trim added chars.
        sqlString = sqlString.substring(0, sqlString.length - 2);
        sqlString += "),\n"
    });
    // trim added comma/newline
    sqlString = sqlString.substring(0, sqlString.length - 2);

    return sqlString
}

insertStatement = buildSqlInsert('Singers', Object.keys(itemsToInsert[0]), itemsToInsert)

const rowCount = await transaction.runUpdate({
    sql: insertStatement,
});
```

Comment: How to identify the row if the incoming data in the form


    {
 "data": {
  "ID":1,
  "Name":"Julie",
  "Job Title":"Programmer"
 },
 {
  "ID":2,
  "Name":"Mark",
  "Job Title":"Quality Anlyst"
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind the rows you want to insert to an array-of-struct parameter and use that in an insert statement like follows:

```
INSERT INTO Singers(SingerId, FirstName, LastName)
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(@struct_array_param)
```

Where `@struct_array_param` is a bound parameter containing array of [`STRUCTS`](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/structs#using_struct_objects_as_bound_parameters_in_sql_queries)(tuples). In addition to being succinct and safer SQL syntax, using bound parameters offers the additional advantage of being able to use the same cached query plan for multiple executions of the same insert statement(with different bound values).